# Integrate ember 2 with laravel 4.2

Tags: ember.js, laravel-4, integration, ember-cli

I am new to ember and am using ember-cli to create a new app.

So far I have successfully completed the ember demo part (using `ember serve`) and need to integrate it with laravel app (under my-test folder) that serves as a REST API.

I have used the command `ember build --environment="production"` and have copied assets folder under Laravel root directory and copied the `index.html` contents to my default Laravel view.

But nothing is working as expected and an error gets displayed in console `'UnrecognizedURLError: /my-test/'`. I have tried almost all resources available in internet and failed to succeed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That error is in the browser console? You might need to set [`rootURL`](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.3.0/configuring-ember/embedding-applications/#toc_specifying-a-root-url) to `my-test`.

Comment: Did you consider to put the backend into subdirectory, namespace it and redirect the namespaced requests into the subdirectory. And of course ember can stay in the root directory and serve the rest of the requests.